# Making java code adapt to the jdk version used

Tags: java, preprocessor, java-7

I recently played around with some new Java 7 features in code that I have to compile with Java 6.

Obviously I get compile errors for the Java 7 code, when building it with the old jdk.

In C#, I would just use the preprocessor to define a version condition and enclose the critical code in an #if-clause.

What's the Java way to do that?

Comment: Write code that targets the correct JDK. You can play some games with simplistic pre-processors. You may be able to use something like a backport library, although I don't know if such a thing exists for, e.g., 7 => 6, unlike for 5 => 4.

Comment: Can you give me an example for a simplistic pre-processor?

Comment: Sed or awk or similar. All it has to do is look for known patterns and include/exclude source. Or use different source files based on a variable in the build system. Doesn't have to be fancy.

Comment: I think I found a new hobby.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking this is not possible.
You can set a target version for javac (-target) or via ant/maven/gradle wrappers.
However this only works for those features which are compatible with lower versions.
You also need a javac of the version you want the source code to read.

The short answer is: no.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can set `-source` and `-target` and make them different. However the only combination which works this way is veraions `1.1` and `1.0`. In all other cases, you need the same version of java for the source and the target.

If you have to use Java 6, I suggest you use that compiler as the libraries also need to be for that version or you can accediently use a library or method which only exists in Java 7. (There are utilities which turn compiled class into older versions but they cannot check for this)

BTW: Java 6 is nearly at the end of free support and Java 6 update 35 could be the last free release. Perhaps its time to be thinking about Java 7 anyway.

Comment: I have to use 1.6.0_23 because it is the newest java that conforms to the companies book of standards :/

Comment: It is two years old next month. ;)